# "like doing ... and doing ..." or "like doing ... and do ..."?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

In the 2 sentences below, which one is correct or both of them are correct?

1. People like reading ghost stories and watch scary films.
2. People like reading ghost stories and watching scary films.

If both of them are correct, is there any difference between them?

Comment: With parallel construction like this, the verbs must match.

Answer (score 1):

As the sentence has a *parallel structure*, both verbs should match, either using an **-ing** form or with a **to-infinitive**, so you could say either:

> People like **reading** ghost stories and **watching** scary films.

OR

> People like **to read** ghost stories and **watch** scary films.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. In further, regarding: "People like reading ghost stories and watch scary films", can "like reading ghost stories" and "watch scary films" be the parallel structure?

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Zhang
"like reading ghost stories" and "watch scary films" are not parallel.  As Astralbee has said, both verbs in the same sentence have to match.

I borrow Astralbee's sentences and bracket the phrases to illustrate.
1)
'People like (reading ghost stories) and (watching scary films).'
2)
'People like to (read ghost stories) and (watch scary films).'

'People like' and 'People like to' have been omitted after the 'and' in 1) and 2), respectively.  Re-inserting them shows that the sentences are still correct.

On the other hand, re-inserting 'People like' into your original example1 will show the error.